# ¿Cómo bajar una rama en git sin mezclarla con la master?

Tags: git

Sucede que cuando clono un repositorio desde git (github), se baja la rama master sin problemas, el punto es que cuando bajo alguna rama del proyecto mediante "git pull origin rama" los archivos que descarga quedan en la carpeta de la rama master y se mezcla todo. Además cuando hago "git branch" solo me aparece la rama master en local. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de trabajar con ramas para evitar que se mezclen?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opción de checkout es la más practica, intenta clonar la rama especifica que necesites, puedes utilizar este comando

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>
```

O

```
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>
```

Donde **branchname** = Es el nombre de la rama que quieras clonar

Donde **remote-app** = Es el link de tu repositorio en la web

Puedes encontrar más documentación:
[git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)
[freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-clone-branch-how-to-clone-a-specific-branch/)
[Respuesta1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch/4568323#4568323)
[Respuesta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Answer (score 1):

Suena a que lo que quieres hacer en realidad es cambiar de la rama master a otra rama. Para ello debes usar el comando checkout. Es decir, si quisieras cambiar a la rama develop, deberías hacer:

```
git checkout develop
```

Comment: Aver si ahora me explico mejor. Entiendo como cambiar de rama, el punto es que 
1. clono un repositorio. por tanto queda una carpeta en local con la rama master recién conalda.

Comment: @Carlos sí cuando clonas no defines que rama vas a clonar, obviamente te descarga la master (si tienes acceso a ella). al darle un checkout cambias de rama, por lo que todos los cambios que hagas no estarán en master, sino en la rama que cambiaste.

Comment: pero para esto tendría que crear la segunda rama en local, ¿no se supone que al hacer git pull origin rama2 esta debiece crearse en el equipo?

se descarga la rama2, pero todos sus ficheros junto a los archivos de la master.

Comment: "¿no se supone que al hacer git pull origin rama2 esta debiece crearse en el equipo?" La respuesta es no. git pull origin rama2 hace exactamente lo que ves que está haciendo: descarga los cambios que estén en la rama2 remota y que no estén en tu rama local actual y los mezcla con tu rama actual.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer checkout de cualquier rama remota y de esa forma evitas crear una rama local:

```
git checkout el-remoto/la-rama
```

Esto te va a dejar en **detached HEAD state**, o sea, trabajando sin una rama. Nada del otro mundo. Puedes hacer checkout luego a otra rama o incluso el warning que te da git cuando quedas en **detached HEAD** te da las instrucciones si quieres crear una rama en ese punto.

y `git branch` solo te va a mostrar ramas **locales**. Si quieres ver las ramas remotas también tienes que colocar `git branch -r` (solo las remotas) o `git branch -a` para que te muestre las locales y las remotas.